# XAML setting property of property

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

In XAML, is there a way to set the property of a property ?

Here is an example to illustrate:

```cs
public class SomeControl : Control
{
    public SomeType SomeProperty { get; } = new SomeType(); // Property deliberately read only 
}

public class SomeType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the XAML below, I want to set the «Name» value of the «SomeProperty» property without adding a setter to «SomeProperty» and therefore without creating a new XAML instance of «SomeType».

```xml
<ns:SomeControl SomeProperty.Name ="Foo"> <!-- here is the idea, but does not compile  -->
</ns:SomeControl>
```

Regards

Comment: it is not possible ... such syntax is for attached properties

Comment: I know this syntax for Attached Properties, but there is no alternative syntax for this need ?

Comment: Are there any good reasons for this to be impossible?

Comment: I don't know? maybe the fact that such syntax is for attached properties and it search for parent of type `SomeProperty`  and `SomeProperty.Name="Foo"` just work as `SomeProperty.SetName(control, "Foo")`

Answer (score 1):

If you make SomeControl.SomeProperty settable, then you can set Name via XAML

```
public class SomeControl : Control
{
    public SomeType SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SomeType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

XAML may be..

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ns:SomeType x:Key="someType" Name="Hello World"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <ns:SomeControl SomeProperty="{StaticResource someType}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I know that if I make SomeProperty settable then I can set the Name property, but in this can, we create a new instance of SomeControl with the XAML, and that's exactly what I want to avoid... That's why I wrote « Property deliberately read only »

Comment: Well... you said "we create a new instance of SomeControl with the XAML, and that's exactly what I want to avoid..." but  `<ns:SomeControl .../>` is object creation. You can't access object without creating it in XAML

Answer (score -2):

Your property is readonly

You cannot set it if it doesn't have a set property

You are even writing: `// Property deliberately read only`

So do you need to set it or is it read only?

Comment: I'm trying to set the value of the Name property which is read/write.